# Подскажите хэш функцию, возвращающую строку короткой длинны

Tags: c#, алгоритм, хеширование

Есть необходимость хранить около миллиона файлов, отличающихся названием. Нужна функция, которая из этих названий (до 100 символов), сделает короткую строку, по которой будет строится дерево каталогов. (Думаю 3-5 вложенных будет достаточно)

Коллизии не важны, нужно равномерное распределение по конечным папкам.

Comment: Берите функцию, возвращающую пустую строку. Короче придумать нельзя, равномернее тоже.

Comment: Как насчет физического пути файла? Отсутствие коллизий гарантируется системой.

Comment: Простой MD5 хэш слишком длинно для вас ?

Comment: Думал об использовании первых символов md5, но не уверен, что это хорошее решение.

Comment: имена файлов уникальны? если так, то используйте буквы из этих имен, или уточните про файлы. Имена файлам даются автоматически или пользователем?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если 32 символа для Вас приемлемо, то можете воспользоваться MD5 (либо кусок MD5, если 32 это много):

```
private string ComputeMD5Checksum(string path)
{
    using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path))
    {
        MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] fileData = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(fileData, 0, (int)fs.Length);
        byte[] checkSum = md5.ComputeHash(fileData);
        string result = BitConverter.ToString(checkSum).Replace("-", String.Empty);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Только хэш вроде от `path` надо было считать.

Comment: @Qwertiy в byte[] можно скастовать что угодно, так что личный выбор каждого. Чисто как пример просто от файла показал.